# "Не советуется" в смысле "не рекомендуется"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Позабавило это употребление в таком смысле. Встретил [тут](https://mamsy.ru/blog/marinuem-myaso-svininy-bystro-i-vkusno/):

> Так как свинина – это жирное мясо, то масло и жирные продукты в маринад ***не советуется*** класть.

*Я правильно понимаю, что это грубая ошибка и что это выражение недопустимо даже для разговорного стиля?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это воспринимается как речевая ошибка: аналогия с "*рекомендуется*" не проходит, поскольку за возвратным глаголом "советоваться" закрепился смысл взаимодействия (обмена советами или испрашивания совета у кого-л.). В разговорной или неформальной письменной речи возможна лишь форма "[знающие люди, мои знакомые, многие] **советуют**".